# Merging two lists and replace elements

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, merge

I'm currently working on an .NET 4.7.2 application. I need to merge 2 lists into 1 and replace certain elements. I'm wondering what is the best approach to achieve this.

The problem is the following: I have a given list of Fruits:

```
Fruits
------
Apple 
Banana 
Orange
Lemon
```

I need to use the Fruits from above in my result list, which gets created using the 2 lists underneath. The lists Template and Selection contain string values only. A, B... will be exact in the same order in Selection and Template. In Template I simply have some Fruit Placeholders added to Selection.

My 2 lists look like this:

```
 Template | Selection
---------------------
  A       |   A
  Fruit   |   Orange
  D       |   D
  Fruit   |   Lemon
  C       |   C
  Fruit   |   B
  B       |
```

The objective is to create a result list, which is based on the Template. I need to replace the Fruit placeholder with a fruit from Selection. If there is no Fruit in Selection, such as in between C and D, I need to take the first available fruit from my Fruits list.

When I create the Result, I cut Orange and Lemon from Fruits - and I just choose the first available fruit from Fruits list to replace the Fruit placeholder in template list e.g. first I cut Orange and Lemon from Fruits, then I pick Apple, because it's still available.

The result looks like looks like this:

```
Result
------
  A
  Orange
  D
  Lemon
  C
  Apple
  B
```

Merging these lists is quite tricky.

My class FruitGarden looks like this:

```
    public class FruitGarden
    {
       public List<string> Fruits { get; set; } // Apple, Banana, Orange, Lemon

       public List<string> PrepareFruits(List<string> Template, List<string> Selection)
       {
          var result = new List<string>();
          var cntSelection = 0;

          for (var cntTemplate = 0; cntTemplate < Template.Count; cntTemplate++){
            // here I need to replace the Fruit in my Template list with an available Fruit from Temporary or from Fruits
              do
              {
              }(cntSelection< Temporary.Count)

            }

          return result;
       }
    }
```

What would you suggest, in C#, what would be a good way to merge the 2 lists into 1?

Comment: What happened to "Apple" and "Banana" from your original list? Where are you getting A-D from?

Comment: Actually, when I create the Result, I cut Orange and Lemon from Fruits - and I just choose the first available fruit from Fruits list to replace the placeholder in template.

Comment: I'm extremely confused about what sort of logic you're after. You're saying you need to merge two lists together, one of which is the first "Fruits" list, but the other is computed, _somewhere_. Can you provide the exact inputs and outputs for this method?

Comment: Show some code. How is an empty item in the `temporary` list represented? Are they guaranteed to be the same length? Have you looked at LINQ `Zip`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you read [ask]?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a good way to solve my issue... What's wrong about my question? :/

Comment: What are the `A`, `B`, ... in your example?

Comment: A, B and so forth is just a random string in my sample.

Comment: Will the random strings always be identical in the Template and Selection?

Comment: you mean A, B, C ... ? Actually no, i can be mixed, but they appear in the same order in Template and Selection.

Comment: What I meant was, would if `Template[0]` is `A`, will `Selection[0]` always be `A` - will they have the same strings in each list? If not, which is copied into `Result`? Also, is it possible for `Template` to end in `Fruit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the random strings can't be `Fruit` and that running out of `Selection`s means using the first left `Fruits`, this is my try:

```
public List<string> PrepareFruits(List<string> Template, List<string> Selection) {
    var result = new List<string>();

    var cntSelection = Selection.Count;
    var cntTemplate = Template.Count;
    var workFruits = new LinkedList<string>(Fruits);
    var idxSelection = 0;
    for (var idxTemplate = 0; idxTemplate < cntTemplate; ++idxTemplate) {
        if (Template[idxTemplate] == "Fruit") {
            if (idxTemplate+1 == cntTemplate || (idxSelection < cntSelection && Selection[idxSelection] != Template[idxTemplate + 1])) { // must be a Fruit selection
                result.Add(Selection[idxSelection]);
                workFruits.Remove(Selection[idxSelection]);
                ++idxSelection;
            }
            else {
                result.Add(workFruits.First());
                workFruits.RemoveFirst();
            }
        }
        else {
            result.Add(Template[idxTemplate]);
            ++idxSelection;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I decided using `LinkedList` would be better than copying the rest of `workFruits` around every time `Selection` skipped a fruit, but which is better probably depends on the number of `Fruits` and the frequency with which `Selection` has missing elements.